# What should I replace WebServiceTemplate with when converting from Spring 3 to Spring 5

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a project I am converting. Most of it was easy but for some reason I can't find a recent implementation of the `org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate` anywhere. Is there a swap out replacement? If not how would I do something similar? It looks to just be serializing. Code looks like...

```
JAXBElement xmlResponse = (JAXBElement) something.getTemplateSearch().marshalSendAndReceive(...)
```

Also we are not allowed to use

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Due to a security issue

Comment: It's from spring-ws-core lol

Comment: yeah either way we aren't allowed to DL them to our local repo due to security concerns

Comment: It is part of Spring-WS not Spring itself, so you don't need to change it. Leave it as is as there is no 5 version of Spring WS.

Comment: @M.Deinum I understand all of that but we have a library that looks for known security vulnerabilities and even the "newest" version is unable to be installed into our maven repo

Comment: You are using Spring Web Services, that isn't part of Spring. You are upgrading Spring **not** Spring WebServices. The version of Spring Web Services that you are using **is** the most recent version. Also **no** the code isn't just serializing it is calling a webservice on a remote system and translates the request and response so no it isn't "just" marshalling.

Comment: I think you still misunderstand I don't want to use Web Services I want to replace it. I know what it is doing the question is for a drop in replacement